# Joining the result of 3 select queries

Tags: sql, database, join

I want to join the following three tables where my condition is t1.eid = 1. After joining the tables I want to fill the empty table cell with 0. I have think to join first t1 with t2 where t1.eid=1 and then joining the result with t3 where the result of the two tables with t3 where t3.vid= the new result.vid.

Data sample:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
sid INT,
fid INT,
eid INT,
i INT,
uid INT);

INSERT INTO t1 (sid, fid, i, eid, uid) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1, 1, 2), (3, 1,
1, 2, 1), (4, 2, 1, 2, 2), (5, 1, 1, 3, 1), (6, 2, 1, 3, 2), (7, 1, 1, 1, 3);


CREATE TABLE t2 (
d INT,
vid INT,
eid INT
);

INSERT INTO t2( d, vid, eid ) VALUES ( 1, 1, 1 ) , ( 1, 2, 1 ) , ( 1, 3, 2 ) , ( 1, 4, 
2 ) , ( 1, 5, 3 ) , ( 1, 6, 3 ) ;

CREATE TABLE t3 (
vid INT,
fr INT,
sr INT,
aj INT,
sj INT,
fid INT,
uid INT
);

INSERT INTO t3( vid, fr, sr, aj, sj, fid, uid ) VALUES ( 1, 0, 100, 0.1, 1, 1, 1 ) , ( 
2, 0, 1000, 1, 1, 2, 2 ) , ( 3, 0, 300, 0.1, 1, 1, 1 ) , ( 4, 0, 200, 1, 1, 2, 2 ) , ( 
5, 0, 1000, 0.25, 10, 1, 1 ) , ( 6, 0, 200, 1, 1, 2, 2 ) , ( 7, 0, 150, 1, 0.1, 1, 1 ) 
, ( 8, 0, 350, 1, 0.1, 1, 1 ) , ( 9, 0, 1050, 10, 0.25, 1, 1 ) , ( 10, 0, 1050, 1, 0, 
2, 2 ) , ( 11, 0, 250, 1, 0, 2, 2 ) , ( 12, 0, 250, 1, 0, 2, 2 ) ;
```

Comment: Please add the image in your post.

Comment: don't let the SO users download the file. much better if you can post here directly or if not, post on [SQLFiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Much better than adding the image, add editable text here in the question

Comment: And would be nice to get the structure of the three query to see what you tried.

Comment: What's the relationship between t3 and either t1 or t2?

Comment: @Bryan t1.eid = t2.eid AND t2.vid = t3.vid

Comment: @JohnWoo Is that an assumption, as I can't see anything in the question that specifies that? The relationship to t3 could equally be `t3.uid = t1.uid`.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*           -- select your desired columns here
FROM    t1 a INNER JOIN t2 b
            ON a.eid = b.eid
        INNER JOIN t3 c
            ON b.vid = c.vid
WHERE  a.eid = 2
```

OR

```
SELECT  b.d, a.fid, a.uid, a.i, a.eid, c.fr, c.sr, c.aj, c.sj
FROM    t1 a INNER JOIN t2 b
            ON a.eid = b.eid
        INNER JOIN t3 c
            ON b.vid = c.vid
WHERE  a.eid = 2
```

you might be wondering why there are letters after the tableName. actually they are called `Alias`. Sometimes helpful when you have longer tableNames.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when I test your queries on my tables I didn´t get the right result since I have a lot of data in my tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.d, t1.fid, t1.uid, t1.i, t1.eid, 
    ISNULL(t3.fr), ISNULL(t3.sr), ISNULL(t3.aj), ISNULL(t3.sj)
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.eid = t2.eid
RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t2.vid = t3.vid
WHERE  t1.eid = 1 OR t2.eid = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But unfortunately still the problem not solved since I have a lot of data in my tables

Answer (score 0):

```
select T2.D,t1.fid,t1.uid,t1.eid,t3.fr,t3.sr,t3.aj,t3.sj 
from T1 
    left outer join T2 ON t1.EID=t2.EID
    Left Outer JOin T3 ON T1.Fid=T3.Fid and T1.Uid=t3.Uid;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your idea helps to solve a part of the result but not all since I have a lot of data in my tables.